# What is node => {this.node = node } in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React I would like to create dropdown with outside click to close

I end up with something like

```
ref={(node) => {this.node = node;}}
```

what does it mean can someone explain this line of code ?

Comment: it creates ref to that element now you can use it to change the attributes/values

Answer (score 8):

This is ref function, a low-level way to assign a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). It assigns a reference to `this.node` property after a component or element was mounted.

A recommended way is to use:

```
this.nodeRef = React.createRef();

...

<Comp ref={this.nodeRef}/>
```

A ref becomes available as `this.nodeRef.current` after a component was mounted. The use of `this.nodeRef` object that can be passed by reference is a way to avoid some common problems that can appear with `this.node`.

Answer (score 1):

The above pattern is a way for assigning refs in React to dom elements. Its known as callback pattern for refs. The callback function in called by react during render with the reference of the element being passed as a prop to the function which you then use and assign to the class variable

More more information, [react the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

Answer (score 1):

```
ref={(node) => {this.node = node;}}
```

Here when you define `ref` using the above method, the function defined is called with the instance of the component/element. i.e. `node` is the element over which `ref` attribute is defined. That instance is then saved in `this.node`